# Содержимое DIV в одну строку на всю ширину

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.

Необходимо вот такую строку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Блок "Каталог товаров" имеет фиксированный размер в строке, необходимо чтобы остальное пространство которое осталось в строке, заполнил блок поиска.

Почти удалось реализовать, но возникла проблема, блок поиска не хочет растягиваться на оставшуюся ширину строки.

Пожалуйста, подскажите как решить проблему?

Ссылка на код: https://jsfiddle.net/en08ygfd/

HTML:

```
<div class="shapka">
    <div class="cat">
        <div>Каталог товаров</div>
    </div>
    <div class="search">
        <input id="oem" name="oem" placeholder="Поиск" type="text"><button type="submit">Найти</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.shapka {background: #e73c3c;padding: 10px 25px;}

.cat {display: inline-block;line-height: 40px;background: #fff;padding: 0 20px;margin-right: 50px;}
.cat div {color: #333;font-weight: 600;text-transform: uppercase;}

.search {display: inline-block;}
.search input {line-height: 36px;border: 1px solid #ccc;padding: 0 12px;}
.search button {line-height: 32px;margin-left: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться типом отображения `flex` следующим образом:

```css
.shapka {
  background: #e73c3c;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  display: flex;
}

.cat {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.cat div {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1; // дает приоритет на растяжение блока
}

.search input {
  flex-grow: 1; // дает приоритет на растяжение блока
  line-height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.search button {
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shapka">
  <div class="cat">
    <div>Каталог товаров</div>
  </div>
  <div class="search">
    <input id="oem" name="oem" placeholder="Поиск" type="text"><button type="submit">Найти</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Посмотрите поддерживаемые браузеры: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex.

Если это вам не подходит, можно воспользоваться табличной версткой.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать функцию calc.
Она будет считать 100% ширины - (ширина блока + ширина отступа).

Например:

```
.search input {
  line-height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0 12px;
  width:calc(100% - 240px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение через [`Booststrap 3`](http://getbootstrap.com/). Использовал [`Grid System`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

**[Ссылка на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/239sctc9/)**